# Upload file to Amazon S3 with non default permission

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to Amazon S3 using .NET SDK. The upload works fine, except it is applying the [default permission](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Model_S3CannedACL.htm) to the uploaded file, which is 'Private'.

I'd like the permission on the uploaded files to be set to 'BucketOwnerFullControl'.

Below is my code, and I'm not quite sure what I need to do to it to get it working as such.

```
    static string accessKeyID = "";
    static string secretAccessKey = "";
    static string existingBucketName = "bucket";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NameValueCollection appConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
        accessKeyID = appConfig["accesskey"];
        secretAccessKey = appConfig["secretkey"];

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\amazontestdirectory");

            foreach (string fileName in files)
            {
                try
                {
                    TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(accessKeyID, secretAccessKey);

                    // Upload a file, file name is used as the object key name.
                    fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileName, existingBucketName);
                }
                catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("AWS error: " + s3Exception.Message, s3Exception.InnerException);

                    //Open a file for writing
                    string errorOutputFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("C:\\amazontestdirectory\\logs\\errorLog.txt");

                    //Get a StreamWriter class that can be used to write to the file
                    if (File.Exists(errorOutputFileName))
                    {
                        StreamWriter objStreamWriter;
                        objStreamWriter = File.AppendText(errorOutputFileName);
                        objStreamWriter.WriteLine();
                        objStreamWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - AWS error: " + s3Exception.Message, s3Exception.InnerException);

                        //Close the stream
                        objStreamWriter.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the permissions while using the TransferUtility you need use the upload override that takes in a TransferUtilityUploadRequest. This lets you set the more advanced options when uploading a file.

```
TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
{
    BucketName = existingBucketName,
    FilePath = fileName,
    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.BucketOwnerFullControl
};

// Upload a file, file name is used as the object key name.
fileTransferUtility.Upload(request);
```

Comment: Yes, after more research I found that I had to use the TransferUtilityUploadRequest. All is working now.